# How to find value of variables so that my expression to be perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose I have the expression
$$\sqrt{p(2-p)} \tag 1$$
and the expression
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left( p-2 \right) ^2-\frac{4\left( p-1 \right) ^4}{\left( p-2 \right) ^2}}. \tag 2
$$
The Mathematica code for the two expressions above reads

```mathematica
Sqrt[(2 - p) p]
Sqrt[1/4 (-2 + p)^2 - (4 (-1 + p)^4)/(-2 + p)^2]
```

I want to know other than $1$, is there some other choice of $p$ that makes both eq(1) and eq(2) not have a square root notation? Obviously when $p=1$, eq(1) becomes $1$ and eq(2) becomes $1/2$. But is there some other choice of $p$? $p=2/10$ will make eq(1) becomes $6/10$ but eq(2) still have a square root $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{493}{5}}}{18}$.

Comment: You don't really mean for your expressions to result in integers though, right? You just want their numerator and denominator to be perfect squares?

Comment: `Plot[1/4 (-2 + p)^2 - (4 (-1 + p)^4)/(-2 + p)^2, {p, -4, 8}]`

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your comment. Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for your comment. There's no root in `Sqrt[(2 - p) p]`  means $p$ is in the interval $[0,2]$. Therefore, a more reasonable plot command might be `Plot[1/4 (-2 + p)^2 - (4 (-1 + p)^4)/(-2 + p)^2, {p, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: Something like `FindInstance[ Sqrt[(2 - k/l) k/l] == n/m && k < 10 && l < 10 && m < 10 &&  n < 10, {k, l, n, m}, PositiveIntegers, 5]`? That's just for the first equation. You have to specify constraints, otherwise `FindInstance` refuses to even try.

Answer (score 1):

The second expression may be simplified by taking 1/4 (p-2)^2 out of the square root. Inside the square root we have then the polynomial:

p1[p_]= 32 p - 72 p^2 + 56 p^3 - 15 p^4

and the question reduces to check if there exists a p so that the value of the polynomial is the square of a rational number:

```
Reduce[32 p - 72 p^2 + 56 p^3 - 15 p^4 == q^2/k^2 , {p, q, 
  k}, PositiveIntegers]

C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1 && p == 1 && q == C[1] && k == C[1]
```

Therefore p==1 is the only solution.

Similar for the first expression:

```
Reduce[(2 - p) p == q^2, {p, q}, PositiveIntegers]

p == 1 && q == 1
```